# How do I place a hyperlink on every page of a SSRS 2005 report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am building a SSRS 2005 report that has potentially multiple pages. I would like to put in a hyperlink so that it appears on the top of every page. The hyperlink links back to the same report - basically I have a "summary" and "detail" mode and want to have hyperlinks to switch between.
So far I tried two approaches:

- Put a textbox in the body, and in Properties -> Navigation, jump to a report. This works fine except it only shows on the very first page.
- Drag the same textbox in the header of the report. Now it appears on every page, but clicking on it results in an error message: "The source of the report definition has not been specified".

google turned up nothing, what now?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to implement the summary report to drill-down into the detail report and use the data on the detail row of the summary report's table to access the detail of that row as a detailed report. For example, let's assume the summary report is a list of invoices with total billed, and the detail report shows the items that were on that invoice.

1. Right-click the InvoiceNumber field in the detail row of the table and choose Properties
2. Click the Navigation tab
3. Click the Jump to report radio button and select the detail report from the drop down list
4. Click the Parameters button and fill in the parameter name and value - in this example, the parameter name might be InvoiceNumber and the parameter value would be =Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value
5. Click OK twice and you now have a hyperlink from the summary report to the detail report where the user can drill-down to get the detail of each invoice
6. Its also good to give a visual indication that this is a hyperlink so I set the Color to MediumBlue

If you just want to link directly to the complete detail report from the summary report and vice versa, you can use the same style on navigation settings but this time do it on a textbox on the header row of your table and make sure that the header has the RepeatOnNewPage property set to True so that it appears on every page.

Answer (score 0):

To make your report go back to the home page

1. Right-click the Title field in the detail row of the table and choose properties
2. Click the Navigation tab
3. Click the Bookmark ID and type ="Home" Click OK twice now have a hyperlink to the home page
4. Place a text box on where pages are being created then right click on it and choose properties
5. Click the Navigation tab
6. Click the Jump to report radio button and put ="Home" Click OK twice
7. type the word Home in the box